# looping over a nested list with multiple rows and columns

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I wanted to replace the items from `listoflist = [[None, None, None]]`  with the output from

```
def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input
```

without creating a new list

`def insertdata(data):` is doing that. its start with the first value and continues till the last value

```
def insertdata(data):
    data_added = False
    n = len(listoflist[0])
    index = 0

    while not data_added and index != n:
            if listoflist[0][index] is None:
                listoflist[0][index] = data
                data_added = True

            else:
                index += 1

            if index == n:
                print("\n The list is full, No more elements will be added \n")



while True:
    insertdata(_execute())
    print(listoflist)
```

I want to extend the function to loop over a nested list with multiple rows.

what condition should the if statment have so it starts at the first row  and execute the inner loop `?

```
def double_loop(data):
    data_added_outer = False
    index_outer = 0
    n_out = len(listoflist)

    # outer loop
    while not data_added_outer and index_outer < n_out:
        if: # what condition ?


            #### inner loop ###############
            data_added_inner = False
            n_inner = len(listoflist[index_outer])
            index_inner = 0
            while not data_added_inner and index_inner != n_inner:
                if listoflist[index_outer][index_inner] is None:
                    listoflist[index_outer][index_inner] = data
                    data_added = True

                else:
                    index_inner += 1

                if index_inner == n_inner:
                    print("\n The list is full, No more elements will be added \n")
            ####### inner ############################################################

    else:
        index_outer += 1
    if index_outer == n_out:
        print("\n The list is full, No more elements will be added \n")
```

Comment: You can just use nested for-loops to simplify everything.

Comment: But seeing it using your approach, you don't need a conditional on the outer loop, because the only condition for adding 'data' is that the item has to be 'None', and that can only be done from the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing the data, the elegant approach in Python is to create new data, using comprehensions:

```
def with_nones_replaced(grid, replacement):
    return [
        [
            replacement if value is None else value
            for value in row
        ]
        for row in grid
    ]
```

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I want to replace the data in the same list without creating a new one, there is a reason behind it which is unimportant in this case

Comment: You can always assign it back in, with something like `old[:] = new`. If you have an efficiency concern then that makes a separate, more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood, the job of your function is simply  to replace the `None` objects in a 2D-List with the `data` parameter passed to the function. I find a for-loop approach much more cleaner, and pythonic in this case.

```
def changedata(arr, data):

    for item in arr:    
        for x in range(len(item)):

            if item[x] is None:
                item[x] = data
```

You can also use the map function to simplify the code:

```
def changedata(arr, data):
    for i in range(len(arr)):

        arr[i] = list(map(lambda x: data if x is None else x, arr[i]))
```

If the data is coming from a function, you can still use this paradigm by calling 
`_execute()` once, storing it in a variable, and then passing it to `changedata()`

```
data = _execute() 
changedata(listoflist, data)
print(listoflist)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the incoming data is comming from a function that waits for input, so the incoming data would be inserted in all "cells" at once, thats why i use a while loop

Comment: What is meant by this? Please clarify.